# Can I avoid 'recommend deletion' for my 'link to plugin' answer?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39046285/4912716) question on SO. OP's sorting issue was easily solved by a plugin for DataTables. He commented that it resolved his problem, but never accepted the answer (Although, it seems he rarely does accept an answer.) Regardless, my answer was 'recommended for deletion' because of the link. I do understand the reasoning against link-only answers. However, I'm asking *what should I have done instead?*

In this *particular* case, the plugin consisted of a single file, so perhaps I should have pasted the code to begin with. What about when the answer involves a library of several files? Should I have commented with a link instead of making it an answer?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: I've read that before and I do believe my 'very short answer' was indeed an answer. I'm also sure I could have done it _better_, but I wouldn't have thought it would get recommended for deletion.

Comment: I did assume that searching 'DataTables US-DateTime plugin' would be helpful if the link died (it brings you straight to the one I referenced.) But I do see how that isn't necessarily helpful, either.

Comment: If the links broke, it's likely a google search wouldn't find anything useful either, I imagine.

Comment: @KeithM You should notice the policies have changed slightly. NAA is for kind of _"I have that problem too"_ and other comment like answers. A link only (if not spam), is still trying to give an answer. If you see such you should probably flag as VLQ.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was told you can't flag positively-scored posts as VLQ.

Comment: @GlenDespaux On second thought, according to the post I linked above, I don't actually think voting to delete your original answer was correct. "Yes, they're both very short, and yes, they contain links. But strip the markup, and you still get at least a little bit of useful information." It's about if you removed the markup, not just if the link stopped working. A post like "You want the plugin [here]" would be VLQ, though, of course. In particular, if it solved the OP's problem, and at least contained the name of the plugin, it doesn't make sense to outright delete it to me.

Comment: @KeithM I appreciate the thought on that. The VLQ vs NAA was what I was trying to show. I was aware it wasn't a _good_ answer, but I truly thought it was still _an answer_

Answer (score 13):

Pasting the contents of a 3rd party plugin into an answer isn't very useful, and depending on the software license may not be entirely legal.

Instead, how about making an example of how to use it, perhaps with some information on why this is a good solution?

Comment: I agree. Wouldn't 'Suggest Edit' be better than deletion? Or is that not how it works? (I'm mostly ignorant of the review queue)

Comment: @GlenDespaux the reviewer can either choose Looks Ok, Edit, Delete or Skip. If they chose Edit what are their options on a link-only answer? Delete is fine.